# validate_pin returnes False when True expected

Tags: python, parameters, boolean

I am writing a function that should return `True` if the `pin` parameter is an `int` that is exactly 4 or 6 digits long, and `False` if it's anything else.

the code below returns `True` as expected:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if type(pin) == int  and len(str(pin)) == 4:
        return True
    elif type(pin) == int and len(str(pin)) == 6:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(validate_pin(1234))
```

while the code below returns `False`, when I expect it to return `True`, I don't know if this is the case for other `pin` parameters that should be `True`:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if type(pin) == int  and len(str(pin)) == 4:
        return True
    elif type(pin) == int and len(str(pin)) == 6:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(validate_pin(0000))
```

how do I fix this mishap? any other feedback is also appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 0000 is equal to 0 (you can check it with print(0000 == 0) and it will return True)
You must pass the pin as a string to the checker method to have 0000 as a string, It's my sample code:

```
def validate_pin(pin: str) -> bool:
    try:
        # If it's not an integer it will raise a ValueError exception
        parsed_pin = int(pin)
        pin_length = len(pin)
        return pin_length == 4 or pin_length == 6

    except Exception as e:
        return False


print(validate_pin('0000'))
```